# How to add a value to a new column and repeated for all existing row

Tags: mysql

I want to add a date column to an existing table. I only want to add the last date of the month (e.g.30 Apr 2023). How do I do this for all the row? Is this possible?

| Date | BLa Bla |
| --- | --- |
| 30 Apr 2023 | Cell 2 |
| 30 Apr 2023 | Cell 4 |
| 30 Apr 2023 | Cell 6 |

and so on.

I am using MySQL. Thanks in advance :D

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ADD Date Date

INSERT INTO table1 (Date)
VALUES ('2023-04-30')
having row_id =1
```

Comment: 1. You need to assign the value into newly created column for existing rows, so you must use not INSERT but UPDATE. 2. Do not use `Date` as column name - this is a keyword and needs in quoting with backticks. 3. If you want to assign the value to newly created column during creation then you may simply specify needed value as default for this column. After the column is created and assigned with this value you may alter the column and remove default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```sql
UPDATE table1
SET `Date` = "2023-04-30";
```

to update all rows with column `Date`.